# JButton changing the color of something back and forth?

Tags: java, swing

I need to make a jbutton change the color of a red circle to green, easy enough. But the color should change between red and green each time you press the button, how do you do that? I can make it change color once but that's it.

here is my panel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class mypanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JButton b;
    Color c1, c2;
    int x, y, z, q;
    public mypanel() {
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        b = new JButton("change color");
        add(b);
        b.setBounds(110, 0, 30, 50);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        c1 = Color.green;
        c2 = Color.red;
        x = 80;
        y = 130;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.requestFocus();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(110, 70, 60, 100);
        g.setColor(c2);
        g.fillOval(125, x, 30, 30);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        if (e.getSource() == b) {
            c2 = c1;
            x = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are `z` and `q`? you don't appear to be using them.

Comment: @Linus He may be using them after having resolved this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needed multiple things changed with your code :

- A third `Color` object to stock the current `Color`
- A way to check if the currentColor is red or green : I used a `boolean`
- Remove the `y` variable.

The most important thing I noticed is your way of changing the values of the current variables. But this makes it impossible to return to the old value since you now have two references pointing to the same object.

You should work on this, read about references or primitive values.

**Note :** This could be simplified but for the sake of clarity, I prefered adding a little more steps. It becomes easier to understand that way.

---

### Solution

```
public class mypanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JButton b;
    Color c1, c2, currentColor;
    boolean isRed = true;
    int x, z, q;
    public mypanel() {
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        b = new JButton("change color");
        add(b);
        b.setBounds(110, 0, 30, 50);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        c1 = Color.green;
        currentColor = c2 = Color.red;
        x = 80;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.requestFocus();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(110, 70, 60, 100);
        g.setColor(currentColor);
        g.fillOval(125, x, 30, 30);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b) {
            if (isRed){
                currentColor = c1;
                x = 130;
                isRed = false;
            } else {
                currentColor = c2;
                x = 80;
                isRed = true;
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I am still very much a beginner so I appreciate the help.

Comment: @heisenfgt You're welcome. If you have any other question, do not hesitate to post. :)

Answer (score 2):

The most direct approach is to add a variable for state and devise a way to draw based on that variable, in this case a boolean variable with suffice:

```
boolean on = false; //when on use green circle
```

Then in your `paintComponent()` change the lines using the colour and position to use this variable:

```
g.setColor(on?c1:c2); //uses green when on
g.fillOval(125, on?y:x, 30, 30); //uses lower position when on
```

With these changes in place you `actionPerformed()` merely needs to update the state:

```
if (e.getSource() == b) 
   on = !on; //toggle state
```

The way we draw is now entirely determined by our current state so we don't change any of the core variables which describe the circles being drawn.